# Declaring an object array in java (code included)?

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
public class Pig {
    private int pigss;
    private Pig[] pigs;

public Pig[] pigNumber (int pigss)
{
    pigs = new Pig [pigss];
    return pigs;
}
```

Code that includes main method:

```
public class animals{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Pig cool = new Pig();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("How many pigs are there?");

    int pigss = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.nextLine() );
    cool.pigNumber(pigss);
    //This is where I have trouble. I want to use the array pigs here in the main method, this is what i tried:

    Pig[] pigs = cool.pigNumber(pigss);
```

I then tried to use a for loop and assign values (String) to the index of arrays (pigs[]). But the error that gives me is: cannot convert from String to Pig. Any tips are appreciated. THank you.

```
     for(int j = 0; j < pigs.length; j++)
     {
      System.out.println("What is the pig " + (j+1) + "'s name");
      pigs[j] = keyboard.nextLine();

    }
```

Comment: Errors are meant to be shown. Please post it on here thanks

Comment: And please post your `Pig` constructors.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pig.

Comment: Which line gives you "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pig"?

Comment: @user3503794 No we mean post the full stack trace of the error inside your question. Go to edit at the bottom and post there. Also include what Elliott said

Comment: public Pig() {  pigss = 0; Pig[] pigs; }

Comment: oh ok I ll do that. Sorry about that

Comment: Why does each Pig instance need to contain an array of pigs?

Comment: this code works fine for me

Comment: sorry i dont know how to post the error on here, but on eclipse, there is a red line under "keyboard.nextLine()" with the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pig"

Answer (score 0):

Your pigs will need an attribute to contain the string values you are trying to pass:

```
public class Pig {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Then when you want to assign this string value to your pig:

```
int indexOfPig = 0; // Or whatever it is supposed to be
pigs[indexOfPig].setName("I am a string");
```

In java you can only use ints as the indexes of arrays

Comment: thanks for your input. I will try all the answers here.

Comment: This might be a bit late but how do I put your code into mine? I have trouble placing it for some reason. I hope it's not too much trouble to ask

Answer (score 0):

It is saying 'cannot convert from String to Pig' because you can't do that!

If you want somehow convert a `String` to a `Pig`, you are going to need to write some code to do the conversion.  For example, you might write a constructor that creates a new `Pig` from some kind of description.  Or you might write a method that *looks up* a `Pig` by name or number or something.

It is hard to offer any more concrete advice because you don't tell us what is in the string values ... or how you *expect* the strings to become pigs.  (The only suggestion I have is to try [Macrame](http://www.angelfire.com/film/karen2/Macrame/Macrame_Animal_Art_03.JPG) :-) )

Comment: I updated my post. If you have time, please look over it. I do agree with you, but having trouble with writing the constructor.

Comment: @user3503794 - Unless you tell us what that trouble is, I'm not sure how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Pig doesn't have a `name` member or even method that accepts a string. Also you are trying to assign a `String`(keyboard.nextline() to a `Pig`(pigs[j].

Add an attribute `name` to your pig.

```
class Pig{
   public String name:
   public void Pig(String name){
        this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Then assign a new instance of `Pig` in the loop.

```
pigs[j] = new Pig(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Also get rid of the useless class `pigNumber`. All you need is an `ArrayList` of `Pig`s. The array list can be dynanically sized.

```
List<Pig> pigs = new ArrayList<Pig>
```

so your loop could be something like

```
 String name = ""
 while(true){
     name = keyboard.readline();
    if(name== "stop"){
        break;
    }
    pigs.add(new Pig(names);
```

}

Then getting the number of pigs is a simple

```
System.out.println(pigs.length());
```

Comment: I'm having trouble placing the top part of your code into mine. I hope it's not too much to ask if you can just put the code where I should put it, that would be really helpful.